# How to pass sql sub query result into RDLC report table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, rdlc

I have to display some data that I get from a sub-query `iif` function in MS Access as follows:

```
select prod,iif(mink>0,mqty\mink,'0')as Carton from products
```

Now, how can I display "Carton" in my RDLC report table?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: any help , ideas please